# Retrieve data for search results from website in R

Tags: r

I am wandering if we could retrieve data for search results from specific website using R Program.
For exampale, in this case, I want to retrieve data when I have search results in the following link:

https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/de/boersenportal/tools-und-services/handelstransparenz/kursblattarchiv/?tradedates=01.12.2017&wkn=EXS1&submit=Suche

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It might be useful to first study the policy of the website regarding webscraping. Check out package `rvest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you can use the `rvest` package for that

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/de/boersenportal/tools-und-services/handelstransparenz/kursblattarchiv/?tradedates=01.12.2017&wkn=EXS1&submit=Suche"
result <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  # The XPath of the table you are interested in
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="Tools_SubModule_PriceHistory_479"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table[2]') %>%
  html_table()

result <- result[[1]]

# Rename columns and remove first row
colnames(result) <- result[1, ]
result <- result[-c(1),]

head(result, 10)
   Zeitpunkt   Kurs Zusatz Umsatz Stück Umsatz in EUR
2   21:55:13 112,55      G         0,00          0,00
3   21:45:13 112,65      G         0,00          0,00
4   21:30:17 112,60      G         0,00          0,00
5   21:15:13 112,55      G         0,00          0,00
6   21:00:13 112,49      G         0,00          0,00
7   20:45:15 112,49      G         0,00          0,00
8   20:30:16 112,54      G         0,00          0,00
9   20:15:19 112,51      G         0,00          0,00
10  20:00:18 112,50      G         0,00          0,00
11  19:45:20 112,62      G         0,00          0,00
```

Since the numbers are all read as strings, there's still some work to do in order to parse them correctly as numbers:

```
options(digits=10)

# Remove all the dots in the numbers
result <- as.data.frame(apply(result, 2, function(y) gsub("\\.", "", y)))

# Substitute all the commas for dots for decimal places
result$Kurs <- gsub("(\\d+),(\\d)", "\\1.\\2", result$Kurs, perl = TRUE)
result$`Umsatz Stück` <- gsub("(\\d+),(\\d)", "\\1.\\2", result$`Umsatz Stück`, perl = TRUE)
result$`Umsatz in EUR` <- gsub("(\\d+),(\\d)", "\\1.\\2", result$`Umsatz in EUR`, perl = TRUE)


result$Kurs <- as.numeric(result$Kurs)
result$`Umsatz Stück` <- as.numeric(result$`Umsatz Stück`)
result$`Umsatz in EUR` <- as.numeric(result$`Umsatz in EUR`)
```

Answer (score 0):

**As an extension to @Jaime Caffarel answer** there are many pages that do not allow this type of techniques. To find out you should look at the address: "https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/robots.txt". You should also look at the terms and conditions of the page as you have said in the comments.

Here is a small function that I usually use, it automatically looks if it is not forbidden and then extracts the function. You **should also leave a reasonable time if you are going to apply on more than one page of the same domain**.

```
polite_scraping <- function(url) {
  require(rvest)
  require(robotstxt)

  if(paths_allowed(url)){
  p <-  url %>% 
      read_html() 

    Sys.sleep(10)

    return(p)
  } else {
    message(":( Not allowed!\n\n\n")
    p <- "NOT ALLOWED"
    return(p)
  }
}
```

**Be polite while scraping!**